# PIP not able to install anything Linaro Debian TinkerBoard

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install few python packages using pip on a tinker board which runs Debian - latest version - for Tinker Board.  However I am not able to install any package and the errors does not say much.  The following is a portion of the error:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 350, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 837, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 323, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 308, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 392, in load_verify_locations
    self._ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 525, in load_verify_locations
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 48, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
Error: []
```

I have use pip for long and the version of pip is 9.0.1 which I guess is the latest.  I have checked the internet connections, time setting, and other basic configurations - which are all in place.

The error appears within couple of seconds - the package is not even downloading.  I am trying to install packages such as scipy, imutils, etc.

Comment: Seems to be OpenSSL-related problem. What version of Python 2.7 do you have? To download packages from the modern PyPI you need at least 2.7.9 (better 2.7.15) and OpenSSL 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around for some solutions, maybe it's a problem related to setuptools?
I am not sure if this will help but you can try with:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: Thank you.  The problem was with corrupt CA Certificates.  After reinstalling them PIP started working.